# Flutter: line spacing affecting first line, problem with Positioned widget as a solution

Tags: flutter

I need to modify the line spacing. Unfortunately, the `height` parameter of `TextStyle` affects the first line as well what you can see here:

```
class Screen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5)),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.yellow,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Text(
            'first line\nsecond line',
            style: TextStyle(height: 2.5, fontSize: 20),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

I immediately thought of a solution: `Stack` with `Positioned` widget, with negative `top` value. **Let's do it in two steps**, first embed it in `Stack`.

```
class Screen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5)),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.yellow,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Text(
                'first line\nsecond line',
                style: TextStyle(height: 2.5, fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output looks exactly like before:

[image]

**Second step:** wrap it with `Positioned` widget.

```
class Screen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5)),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.yellow,
        child: Stack(
//          fit: StackFit.loose,
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned( // .fill
              top: -20,
//              bottom: 0,
//              left: 50,
//              right: 0,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Text(
                  'first line\nsecond line',
                  style: TextStyle(height: 2.5, fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

This is almost what I wanted. However, if you pay attention to the colors, what was before blue, is now yellow. Adding `Positioned` widget makes `Stack` to be expanded rather than fit the content - that prevents me from using it in more complex layouts - e.g. ListView. Flutter outputs warning `RenderStack object was given an infinite size during layout.`

I noticed that Positioned widget does it as soon as you add any of top/left/bottom/right - before it fits the content. I tried to experiment with Stack's `fit` property, of Positioned with `.fill` initializer, but I didn't succeed.

Comment: I think the first step is to rethink your layout. The hardcoded negative padding will result in a broken UI as soon as someone changes their preferred font size from the OS settings. Do you know beforehand where the line breaks are, or was that just a bad example? If you do, then why not apply different styling to the first and 2nd lines? If you don't, you'll need some more complex logic that calculates what fits on the first line and what doesn't..

Comment: You are right, changing font size in system settings may mess up my calculation. Maybe I could get that settings and adjust the constants. But what's wrong with the layout? I need to change line spacing for better typography. And no I don't know where like breaks gonna be, as this is generic component used everywhere and my app supports many languages

Comment: Have you tried applying `strutStyle` to the `Text` with a custom `leading` value? The result should be similar, but that value would remain constant regardless of font size, so that might allow using the negative padding without any side effects.